# creating a public postgres AWS database

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a postgres RDS database on AWS that's accessible to the public without the need for SSH tunnelling.  This is for development only.   I've created a Separate AWS VPC and assigned gateways and two subnets to it.  when I created the database I set it to be public.  The security group  rules are

Inbound(Custom TCP Rule,TCP 5432,0.0.0.0/0)
outbound (All traffic,All,All,0.0.0.0/0)

I can't seem to connect to this database with my local pgadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable your VPC attributes to have DNS hostnames and DNS resolution enabled? These must be set in order for your DB instance to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Yep I did this,  I can't set the public flag on the RDS setup without it

Comment: Hm, I have the exact same set up as you and was able to connect to my public RDS using pgadmin. My VPC has 2 subnets, both subnets are in a network acl that has a routing table that allows all inbound. My security group only allows inbound tcp 5432 from 0.0.0.0/0. Can you try running `telnet yourrds.fdsaj4mph17.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` to verify the RDS is reachable?

You should see "Connected to ec2-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: thanks I had the subnets and ACLs set correctly but your response made me double check the settings in which I determined that I didn't have both subnets associated to the route table,  once I added that it worked.  Also Im familiar with the telnet trick to verify DB connections but I read somewhere that amazon AWS didn't allow Telnet connections.  That was wrong I was able to verify the connection with tellnet,  Very cool!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I verified I had at least two subnets which ACLs allowed connection to the internet but one of the subnets wasn't associated to the route,  when I added it I was able to connect to it